# matrix of multiplication by primitive element of number field in SageMath

Tags: number-theory, sagemath

I never used [Sage](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)  and I would like to check some results on Sage but I really don't know how.

First I need to create a number field ($\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ for instance).
Then I would like to find or select a suitable basis $(1,\sqrt 2$).
I would like at last to find the matrix multiplication, say by $\sqrt 2$ in that selected basis.

Could you please help? I tried unsuccessfully the following:

> k. = NumberField(x^2 - 2)
>
> a^4
>
> k.basis()

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation on number field elements](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/number_field/number_field_element.html) and search for 'matrix'

```
sage: K.<a> = NumberField(x^2 - 2)
sage: a.matrix()
[0 1]
[2 0]
sage: (a^4).matrix()
[4 0]
[0 4]
```

The standard basis used here is the list of powers of the primitive element, that is $(1,\sqrt{2})$ in this case.

As the documentation states, this is the matrix for right multiplication; the *rows* are the images of the basis vectors. You can take the transpose if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you! is there a way to specify the basis? I don't really want the power basis. For instance if I have $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3]$ I want to use the basis $(1,\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3,\sqrt 2\sqrt 3)$?

Comment: That functionality seems to be not built in, but you can express your favorite basis in terms of Sage's standard basis, and then expressing a matrix in your favorite basis is just linear algebra.

Comment: That's right! It looks like it's missing. Thank you